# Python Regex extract html file content within tags

Tags: python, html, regex

I have lots of html format files in a folder. I need to check whether each of them contains this tag:

```
<strong>QQ</strong>
```

and need to extract only "QQ" and its content.
I first read one of the files to test, but it seems my regex does not match.
If I replaced fo_read as the tag

```
<strong>QQ</strong>
```

it will match though.

```
fo = open('4251-fu.html', "r")
fo_read = fo.read()
m = re.search('<strong>(QQ)</strong>', fo_read)
if m:
    print 'Match found: ', m.group(1)
else:
    print 'No match'
fo.close()
```

Comment: Have you considered using an html parser instead? [Using regex to parse HTML is scary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5067311).

Comment: I have beautifulsoup, but there are several strong tags in the html though. How can it work?

Comment: If you have multiple tags than that's another reason to use an HTML parser instead. I'm not familiar with the subject, but either the BS4 docs or [the standard html module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html) (oops: [python2 for you](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html)) docs and some targeted googling should be helpful.

Comment: Do you need extract <strong>Question-and-Answer Session</strong> or the text the following it? If former, one paragraph, few, a section ..until next enclosing div etc...?

Comment: I need the text following it. But I just think maybe need to confirm if the file has this tag first? because not all of them has this tag though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result = soup.find("strong", string=re.compile("Question-and-Answer Session"))
if result:
    print("Question-and-Answer Session")
    # for the rest of text in the parent
    rest = result.parent.text.split("Question-and-Answer Session")[-1].strip()
    print(rest)
else:
    print("no match")
```

Comment: it returns [u'\n    Question-and-Answer Session\n   '], how can I only get Question-and-Answer Session?

Comment: you could add a `.strip()` to the end of `result.parent.text.split(...)[-1]`

Comment: splitting is a bit hacky, try `next_sibling` for any serious project.... https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#going-sideways

Answer (score 0):

You can try with BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
f = open('4251-fu.html',mode = 'r')
soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'lxml')
search_result = [str(e) for e in soup.find_all('strong')]
print search_result
if '<strong>Question-and-Answer Session</strong>' in search_result:
    print 'Match found'
else:
    print 'No match'
f.close()
```

Output:

```
['<strong>Question-and-Answer Session1</strong>', '<strong>Question-and-Answer Session</strong>', '<strong>Question-and-Answer Session3</strong>']
Match found
```

Comment: There are several strong tags, but I only want the one with Question-and-Answer Session

Comment: But strong tags are in different places, not always in the beginning.

Comment: it will find all strong tag in html file, no matter where it is.